# Pick data from variable via .substring(10,20) error with the value greater than 10 in powershell

Tags: powershell

Why cant I get the data from "$final.Substring(10,23)" and "$final.Substring(24,31)"?
It looks like it will fail as soon I'm past the range of 9.

The error I get is as follows..

> Exception calling "Substring" with "2" argument(s): "Index and length
>   must refer to a location within the string. Parameter name: length" At
>   line:34 char:1
>   + $thirdOct = $final.Substring(10,23)
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentOutOfRangeException

```
$final = "01234567890123456789012345678901"

$firstOct = $final.Substring(0,8)
$secondOct = $final.Substring(8,16)
$thirdOct = $final.Substring(10,23)
$fourthOct = $final.Substring(24,31)


Write-Host $firstOct
Write-Host $secondOct
Write-Host $thirdOct
Write-Host $fourthOct
```

Comment: What the name of second parameter of `Substring`?

Comment: Ahhhhh... guess it's getting late, the second parameter is just the range, not an endpoint!

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter is `length`, not `endindex`.

```
$final.Substring.OverloadDefinitions
string Substring(int startIndex)
string Substring(int startIndex, int length)

PS-ADMIN > $final.Length
32

PS-ADMIN > 10+23
33
```